# How to move image to new folder?

Tags: php, image, rename, crop, resize-image

As the title says ..How to move/rename image to new folder?
I have this so far and the new image is resized/cropped but it doesn't move to "new/" folder:

```
$in_filename = '4csrWqu9ngv.jpg';

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);

$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 0;

$new_height = $height - 65;
$new_width  = $width;

$image     = imagecreatefromjpeg($in_filename);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_image);

$move_new = imagejpeg($new_image);

rename($move_new, 'new/' . $move_new);
```

As always any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had few mistakes in your code. Output of `imagejpeg` is a boolean, so your rename always failed. You also never saved resized image. You have to use 2nd parameter of `imagejpeg` and provide proper filename of new image. Also, make sure directory `new` exists, else rename will fail.

Fixed code:

```
$in_filename = '4csrWqu9ngv.jpg';

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);

$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 0;

$new_height = $height - 65;
$new_width  = $width;

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($in_filename);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);

/* Uncomment in case you want it also outputted
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_image);
*/

imagejpeg($new_image, $in_filename);

rename($in_filename, 'new/' . $in_filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the "new" folder exist? If not, you need to create it at first using [`mkdir`](http://php.net/mkdir).